# How to check is maximized any window in XFCE?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to change top panel color and alpha when any window is maximized.
For now I have something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 = 1 ]
do
    if window_is_maximized
    then
        xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/background-alpha -s 100
    else
        xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/background-alpha -s 50
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Maximized windows in X do not have a special state that you can test reliably.  From a script, you can use `xwininfo`:

- You can check if the window *happens* to be the same size as the root (main) window, and its position is the upper-left corner.
- If you *happen* to be using a window manager which supports certain [EMWH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) properties (`_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN`, `_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT`, `_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ`), your script could check for those. But in a quick check for window managers which might do that, I found none.